How to interpret uncertainty when data is observational
When data is observational for example in administrative contexts how do we interpret frequentist statistical measures of uncertainty for example confidence intervals?
For example in a school of 500 students in 2023 we measure the GPA of all 500 students. The average GPA is a fixed quantity for this particular group of students.
In order to conceptualize frequentist uncertainty do we propose that these 500 students are members of a population?
For example we might state that the students may represent broader students in the community or that each year there is new students and that a single year is a sample of all possible years of students. Another conceptualization is if we turned back time and students relived the year their school experiences would be different, and the GPA will be different.
This fuzziness in definition of a population I am trying to wrap my head around. Does the population I decide to be the one of interests inform the analysis for example how to calculate confidence interval?

There is no "right" answer to your question, as you say it all depends on what your population of interest is. If your population is the class of 2023 then there is no need for inference. If your population is some hypothetical group of students of which the class of 2023 is a sample of 500, then incorporating uncertainty is appropriate, but which option you choose is up to you/your client

Does the population I select to be of interest inform the formula I use to measure uncertainty?
